# How to set Grid in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

Hi I am working on a vaadin application integrating the vaadin app in the application UI . The image is : [image]

> the Scroll bar is up and grid is below.

For setting a grid i have tried `setSizeFull()` and `layout.setSizeUndefined()` but it's not working for the grid..

this happens when i add object of BeanItemContainer to the grid.

```
BeanItemContainer<Partner> container = new BeanItemContainer<Partner>(Partner.class, model.getPartnerList());
        Grid grid = new Grid();


         grid.setColumns("code","surname","name","companyName");

         grid.getColumn("code").setHeaderCaption("Code");
         grid.getColumn("lastname").setHeaderCaption("Last Name");
         grid.getColumn("name").setHeaderCaption("First Name");
         grid.getColumn("companyName").setHeaderCaption("Company");

         //grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
        layout.addComponent(grid);
        addComponent(layout);
        return layout;
```

Comment: please add some relevant code and maybe a screenshot, that shows the problem - at least i don't understand what "the scroll bar is up and grid is below" (why is that a blockquote?)

Comment: @cfrick the image is added

Comment: thanks.  maybe also relevant: what exact vaadin version and what browser.  since the scrollbar is already in the second half of the way down, has the scrolling any effect? what theme is this and is the theme loaded fully and properly? with valo the grid headlines looks way different.

Comment: @cfrick Vaadin Version7.6,, Google chrome and firefox both are showing the same, Valo theme

Comment: You should not put a component with relative size (e.g. 100%, `setSizeFull()` in a layout with undefined size. The result is undefined, since 100% from undefined is meaningless.

Comment: Can you show us the code, so that we can see how your components are nested?

Comment: Can you check your theme scss if it contains ``$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, grid);``

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar Yes it is threre .. Should i remove it?

Comment: @A. Meier the code is updated

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar I am working on some urgent task from few days ...pardon me i will post it soon .. thanks dhs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this error too.

A developer who compiled the theme when project started had

`$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, grid);`
in the theme scss file.

Please comment this line out or remove the line completely and try again